# PIVOT a Select query

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2012, crystal-reports-2008

I'm new to SQL server coding and I needed some help.

I have a `SELECT` statement that has three columns, i.e. the field name that is changed and its previous and new values

```
FieldName   OldValue    NewValue
Age         21          22
Age         76          54
Color       Red         Blue
```

I'm trying to `PIVOT` this select into something like:

```
OldValueName   NewValueName  OldValueAge  NewValueAge  OldValueColor  NewValueColor etc.
```

Can you please help me with that?

Comment: provide a result example for this sample data

Comment: so if you have 100 rows result from that SELECT statement, you want to PIVOT it into 300 columns x 1 row result ?

Comment: use cross tabs in crystal reports

Answer (score 0):

You may do by this as below use of PIVOT.

```
DECLARE @tbl TABLE (
    FieldName VARCHAR(50),
    OldValue VARCHAR(50),
    Newvalue Varchar(50)
)

INSERT INTO @tbl ( FieldName, OldValue, NewVALUE )
SELECT 'AGE', '21','22'
UNION
SELECT 'AGE', '76','54'
UNION
SELECT 'color', 'red','blue'

SELECT * FROM @tbl

SELECT * FROM 
(
    SELECT FieldName, OldValue, NewValue  FROM @tbl
) AS S
PIVOT
(
    max(OldValue) FOR s.FieldName in ([AGE], [color])
) AS Pvt
```